# Python ECDSA, sign with private key with curve secp224k1

Tags: python, ecdsa

I'm really having a hard time getting to get to grips with this 3rd party Python module.
I'm trying to *sign a 28-byte SHA-224 digest using a 28-byte SHA-224 digest private key under secp224k1*.

My attempt:

```
import ecdsa

private_key = int("b89ea7fcd22cc059c2673dc24ff40b978307464686560d0ad7561b83", 16).to_bytes(28, byteorder='big')
digest_msg = int("d8af940293347bc348df1896b0d93bf3952399702cef4fbf199d1cf4", 16).to_bytes(28, byteorder='big')

sk = SigningKey.generate(private_key, curve=ecdsa.secp224k1) 
sig = sk.sign_digest(digest_msg)

>> AttributeError: module 'ecdsa' has no attribute 'secp224k1'
```

Hopelessly, I can't even google my way out of this error.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa)?

Comment: As far as I now, ecdsa only allows you to use `secp224r1` curve, but not `secp224k1`. Also, for using an existing key you should use `SigningKey.from_string(private_key, curve=NIST224p)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the `fastecdsa` for doing this type of task.

As far as I know, `ecdsa` does not support `secp224k1` curve.

`fastecdsa` does not support importing the key from a string, but you can export it to a `pem` format and import it using `keys.import_key()`.
Check it [here](https://github.com/AntonKueltz/fastecdsa/blob/master/fastecdsa/keys.py).

```
from fastecdsa import keys, curve, ecdsa

#generating the private key over secp224k1 curve
private_key = keys.gen_private_key(curve=curve.secp224k1)

#get the public key from the corresponding private key
public_key = keys.get_public_key(private_key, curve=curve.secp224k1)

msg = "Sign this message with secp224k1"

r, s = ecdsa.sign(msg, private_key, curve.secp224k1)

print(ecdsa.verify((r, s), msg, public_key, curve.secp224k1))
```

Output:

```
True
```